# How to convert array element into object with conditionally true and one string value in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

What is a more compact way to convert `color=["red", "green", "blue", "Other"]` into `colorObjFinal = { blue: true, green: true, Other: "Other", red: true }`?

This is my long function, I would like to shorten it:

```js
let color = ["red", "green", "blue", "Other"];
let colorObj;
let colorObjFinal = {};
console.log("color:", color);

colorObj = color.reduce((a, v) => ({
...a,
[v]: v
}), {});
console.log("colorObj:", colorObj)

for (var key in colorObj) {
    if (colorObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(key == 'Other'){
        colorObjFinal[key] = colorObj[key];
      } else {
        colorObjFinal[key] = true;
      }
    }
}

console.log("colorObjFinal:", colorObjFinal)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just do it all in 1 go:

```js
let color = ["red", "green", "blue", "Other"];

let result = color.reduce ((a,v) => ({
  ...a,
  [v] : v == "Other" ? v : true
}),{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your first `Array.reduce` to get the result.

```js
let color = ["red", "green", "blue", "Other"];

const result = color.reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc[item] = (item != "Other") ? true : item;
   return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

that ? (is arguably the most compact writing here)

```js
let color = ["red", "green", "blue", "Other"];

const res = color.reduce((a,c)=>(a[c]=c=='Other'?c:true,a),{});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **Array.reduce** function here:

```js
const color=["red", "green", "blue", "Other"];
const transformedObj = color.reduce((a,b)=> ({...a, [b]: b !=="Other"? true: "Other"}),{});
console.log(transformedObj )
```